# Apache Cassandra - Accessor with LIMIT as a parameter not working

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to pass a parameter to the Accessor query. I have the following:

```
@Accessor
public interface ActivityAccessor {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM activity WHERE user_id = :id limit :limit")
    Result<UserActivity> findUserActivityByUserId(@Param("id") Long ownerId, @Param("limit") int limit);
}
```

Calling the accessor method with:

```
MappingManager manager = new MappingManager (getSession());
ActivityAccessor activityAccessor = manager.createAccessor(ActivityAccessor.class);
Result<UserActivity> activities = activityAccessor.findUserActivityByUserId(userId, 20);
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:99 no viable alternative at input 'limit' (... LIMIT :[limit])
```

However, when I change the accessor method to explicitly state the limit value it works just fine:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM activity WHERE user_id = :id limit 20")
Result<UserActivity> findUserActivityByUserId(@Param("id") Long ownerId);
```

Does anyone have a clue why is this happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`limit` is a reserved CQL keyword and cannot be used as a named parameter. Change it for something else. e.g.:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM activity WHERE user_id = :id limit :max")
Result<UserActivity> findUserActivityByUserId(@Param("id") Long ownerId, @Param("max") int limit);
```

Comment: Thanks! Thought it wouldn't matter because params would be replaced with actual values but I guess it does matter.

Comment: How strange, I thought the same that it won't matter and was wrong. Can't use limit keyword as the named parameter.